# Spark 2.1.1 Memory Leak Detected

Tags: apache-spark, memory-leaks

While using Spark 2.1.1, I am seeing "Managed memory leak detected" errors in my log file with no other stack traces. Should I be concerned about these errors?  Do they suggest an underlying problem in my code?

Here are my settings:

```
spark.master=local[*]
spark.memory.storageFraction=0.2
```

Log messages below:

```
[Stage 1:======================================================>(615 + 1) / 616]
[Stage 2:===>                                                   (42 + 17) / 616]
[Stage 2:=====>                                                 (64 + 16) / 616]
[Stage 2:=======>                                               (83 + 16) / 616]
[Stage 2:========>                               00:57:11 ERROR org.apache.spark.executor.Executor  - Managed memory leak detected; size = 5286192 bytes, TID = 1365
              (102 + 16) / 616]
[Stage 2:==========>                                           (125 + 16) / 616]
[Stage 2:============>                                         (145 + 16) / 616]
[Stage 2:==============>                                       (164 + 17) / 616]
[Stage 2:===============>                                      (181 + 16) / 616]
[Stage 2:=================> 00:57:11 ERROR org.apache.spark.executor.Executor  - Managed memory leak detected; size = 5274642 bytes, TID = 1448
                                   (203 + 16) / 616]
[Stage 2:===================>                                  (227 + 17) / 616]
[Stage 2:=====================>                                (248 + 16) / 616]
[Stage 2:======================>                               (261 + 18) / 616]
[Stage 2:========================>                             (284 + 16) / 616]
[Stage 2:==========================>                           (307 + 16) / 616]
[Stage 2:============================>                         (330 + 16) / 616]
[Stage 2:==============================>                       (352 + 17) / 616]
[Stage 2:================================>                     (375 + 16) / 616]
[Stage 2:==================================>                   (39600:57:14 ERROR org.apache.spark.executor.Executor  - Managed memory leak detected; size = 5359872 bytes, TID = 1667
```

Comment: That's possible, but I am surprised to see this error still showing up in 2.1.1. Also, the 1.6.0 posting above refers to the TaskMemoryManager.  In this case, it's the org.apache.spark.executor.Executor that is throwing the Error.